# Как внести то, что выводит help(), в переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Функция help() возвращает `None` и выводит в консоль описание команды.

Как получить это описание в переменную?

Comment: А почему бы не взять атрибут `__doc__` из интересующего объекта? Или нужно не то описание?

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, годно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[(c) Aaron Altman:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11266394/5741205)

```
import pydoc

help_str = pydoc.render_doc(<class or object>)
```